# YAML values not getting returned correctly

Tags: java, configuration, yaml

I've got a YAML file that looks like this:

```
---
name:
  storage:
    documentfiles:
      username: rafa
      password: hello
```

And I'm trying to get the last two `username` and `password` values. My current code is the one below. I'm using a Map to store the YAML values, but since there is more than one child when I `map.get()` anything past `name` it gives me a null value. if I do `map.get(name)` I get `{storage={documentfiles={username=rafa, password=hello}}}` Does anyone know how I can correctly get the username and password?

```
public Map grabYaml(){
    Yaml reader = new Yaml();

    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(yamlFileName);
    Map map = (Map) reader.load(inputStream);

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public class Test {

    public Map grabYaml() throws IOException {
        Yaml reader = new Yaml();

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(yamlFileName));
        Map map = (Map) reader.load(inputStream);

        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map storage = (Map) new Test().grabYaml().get("name");
        Map documentfiles = (Map)storage.get("storage");
        Map userData = (Map) documentfiles.get("documentfiles");

        System.out.println(userData.get("username"));
        System.out.println(userData.get("password"));
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the `obj` in the first line?

Comment: it's instance variable of the class

Comment: i'm calling grabYaml() from within the same class it is created. Regardless, using the structure, it still gives me the nullpointer exception on the `documentfiles` line.

Comment: @ralphie9224 i updated my full class, hope it helps.